# How to find if there is an xls file in a folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to find if there is an .xls file in a folder.  This is the code I have:

```
import calendar
import datetime
import glob
import shutil
from smtplib import SMTP
import os
from pathlib import Path
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

Today = datetime.datetime.today()

my_file = Path("C:\\Users\\Smith\\folder1\\*.xls")
if my_file.is_file():
    print("File Exists")
else:
    time.sleep(5)
```

It doesn't like the syntax I've used to define the file.

All suggestions welcome!  Thanks!

Comment: `glob.glob("C:\\Users\\Smith\\folder1\\*.xls")` returns any matching files in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `glob`:

```
import glob
import os

pat = "C:\\Users\\Smith\\folder1\\*.xls"
if any(os.path.isfile(file) for file in glob.glob(pat)):
    print("File Exists")
else:
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!